# Taskbar has a "ghost" taskbar with icons underneath it

Tags: windows-11

[image]

As you can see in the image you there is a "shadow" task bar underneath my main task bar. Safari, Skype, other random icons.

- Machine: Lenovo Thinkpad Fresh system format (remove everything),
  re-install windows 11.
- If I allow the taskbar to hide, I can still
  see the shadow of this other taskbar.
- I cannot interact with this at all
- This persists through restarts of the machine and explorer
  processes.

Comment: Burn-in on OLED screen? If you cannot take a screenshot, then that is most likely the issue.

Comment: I don't usually see burn-in on a modern machine (it could happen, though)..  Try running the Lenovo Driver Update App and update all drivers.

Comment: All drivers updated. I don't think it's burn in. I don't see it when starting up the machine and you get the lenovo loading screen Also some of the apps showing I've never had installed (safari)

Comment: @Prescott, was the machine brand-new, or a demo unit?